# 301 редирект на основной домен и проблемы со старым SSL

Tags: .htaccess, https

Сайт долгое время был доступен под доменом **https://site.ru**, теперь, я решил использовать международный домен и прикрепил на сайт новый домен **https://site.com**

Теперь со старого домена происходит 301-редирект всех страниц на новый домен:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://site.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Для старого домена был установлен SSL сертификат, и в поисковиках сайт проиндексирован как https://site.ru - теперь старый сертификат просрочен и больше не действует. А на новом домене установил новый SSL.

Когда по ссылке без HTTPS проходишь: site.**ru**/page/1 происходит редирект на site.**com**/page/1

А когда люди заходят на сайт через поисковики ссылка такая: **https://site.ru/page/1** и редирект не происходит, а выдает ошибку SSL (Подключение не защищено).

Как решить данный вопрос?

Comment: Решение одно - [сгенерировать сертификат](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/letsencrypt) для site.ru!

Comment: @norbornen в смысле для site.ru нужно установить SSL?

Comment: @Maqsood да . .